# What is the correct way to wait for the API response, in the sense of interface in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, async-await

When a screen where the main content comes from an API, what would be the option to have a good **UI**? Should this really be done with FutureBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use FutureBuilder and use different states to inform your users.
For example:

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: _getMark(context),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return snapshot.data as Widget;
        }

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          //show error
        }

        return markUnRead;
      },
    );
```